# Which framework for web&WebSocket?

Tags: apache, websocket

I'm looking for framework which I will use for web projects and together with WebSocket. I have one server (apache) and I can't change anything else other than installing new mods - exclude this if there is no any framework which have support for running on just one server or it doesn't have a good documentation. It would be great if WebSocket could be running in the background and not in console all the time.

I've watched Python which looks promising and I have experience with PHP, but there is question how I would solve the problem of continuous running WebSocket. I actually don't know where to start and which language I should choose, so I would like to ask you for help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already lean towards scripting, then you should take a look at Node.JS, which will allow you to have both http and WS running at the same time. The best WS implementation on Node.JS is https://github.com/einaros/ws, and you can run it alongside the Node.JS native http server.

If you are attached to more commercial level solution where you have only one server, then take a look at Kaazing, but keep in mind that server running by itself is geared towards pure HTML5+WS applications, in other words, you write rich HTML5 apps that run in the browser and leverage whatever protocol is most suitable for the application. Kaazing will run alongside with Apache, though, if you want to keep Apache and still use CGI.